# PhoneGap Facebook plugin, how to get firstname, lastname, image?

Tags: facebook, cordova

how to get firstname, lastname and image from facebook user after login ?
Here is the my code

```
    function onDeviceReady()
    {
      var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'success';
}

facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
    fbLoginSuccess,
    function (error) {  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'error'; }
);  
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function loginFb() {
  openFB.loginFb(
  function(response) {
  if(response.status === 'connected') {

    openFB.api({
    path: '/me',
    success: function(data) {

      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      fbUserName = data.name;
      fbUserId = data.id;
      fbUserPic = document.getElementById("fbuserPic").src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + data.id + '/picture?type=small';
    }
    });
  }
  });
}
```

Hello, if you have any facing problem then tell me OK.